# ASP.NETでperfectscrollbarが使用できない

Tags: asp.net

問題はタイトルの通りなのですが、ASP.NETのWebフォームにてperfectscrollbarというjQueryプラグインを使用しようとしたところ、

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript 実行時エラー: オブジェクトは 'perfectScrollbar' プロパティまたはメソッドをサポートしていません。

上記のエラーにより実行することができませんでした。
記述等は各解説サイトを参考に、もっともシンプルなものを使用しているので、間違ってはいないはずなのですが…

個人的にはASP.NETと併用しているという情報が検索でヒットしないことから、そもそもASP.NETでは使えないものなのか、という点でも疑問に思っています。

何か情報をご存じの方おりましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: エラー内容からは該当のJSファイルが読み込まれる前にメソッドを呼び出しているだけのように見えますが、`script`タグの順序は正しいですか？

Answer (score 0):

headタグ直下に
1.jQuery
2.perfectscrollbar（プラグイン）
3.config(実行記述)

で読み込まないとそのエラーが出ると思います。